# Multiline messages in chainsaw

Tags: logging, apache-chainsaw

I'm using chainsaw 2.1.0 snapshot from http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy/
I was able to set it up to parse a log file, but it always splits multiline messages into multiple one-line messages (including all the other fields into the first message)
How can I make it parse multiline messages correctly? Is there any workaround or alternative?

Edit: a few lines from the file:

```
[<proceed>(2)] INFO 2013-01-16 05:04:23,728 xmlstream.py:start_tls:740 ::: Negotiating TLS :::
[<proceed>(2)] INFO 2013-01-16 05:04:23,729 xmlstream.py:start_tls:741 ::: Using SSL version: 3 :::
[<proceed>(2)] DEBUG 2013-01-16 05:04:23,838 xmlstream.py:start_tls:809 ::: CERT: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDaDCCAtGgAwIBAgIKMfrHUQAAAABbMDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBGMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UEChMKR29vZ2xlIEluYzEiMCAGA1UEAxMZR29vZ2xlIElu
dGVybmV0IEF1dGhvcml0eTAeFw0xMjA2MDUwMDUyMTRaFw0xMzA2MDUwMTAyMTRa
MGMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1N
...
Zfhf9Lio+EplEmBc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 :::
```

and the log format is `"[NDC] LEVEL TIMESTAMP FILE:METHOD:LINE ::: MESSAGE :::"`
(I attempted to put unique separators before and after the message to help with parsing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting 'appendNonMatches' to false in the receiver configuration.

If that doesn't work, provide a few lines of your log file (a mix of single and multi-lines) and I can tell you what you need to do configuration-wise.

It might be a bug too, will have to see.

A few notes after your responses:

- AppendNonMatches=false is probably ok if you are using a single logging framework/layout (not randomly embedding printf-style output)..but..missed matches are dropped on the floor with this set to false, so beware..
- I've never bothered testing with an end delimiter for the message - it is pretty much required that the message is the last field in the log message, because of the potential variability of the content in the message field.
- If you have multiple lines starting with: (tab)at - those fields should be converted into to the throwable field.

Comment: Thanks, that somewhat helps, but in the example I added, it appends the "CERT" entry to the "Using SSL" entry, including all the fields (such as DEBUG) in the message

Comment: After removing the "end separator", it's working as expected, although I'm not convinced this is the best way to do it (appending to previous message for parsing failures)

Comment: And a further question would be how to get chainsaw to parse non-java stack traces (also multi-line, but separate from the message) into the THROWABLE field

Comment: Sounds like chainsaw's parsing involves a lot of guesswork; while that is not satisfactory, your explanation is.  
Maybe logging in some xml format is the way to go?

Comment: It's not guesswork, it's regular expression parsing of your pattern.  The 'logformat' keywords and prop(propname) fields just end up being groups which are used to re-generate a log event.  You can see that in the chainsaw-log tab.  XML would work, either via a UDP/MulticastAppender or a fileappender.  There is an xmlfilereceiver, but it doesn't support VFS (and reliable tailing), like VFSLogFilePatternReceiver does.

Comment: The guesswork is the part that doesn't involve parsing the given pattern - guessing that non-matching lines belong to a multi-line message, and guessing that lines starting with (tab)at belong to the throwable field. It would be preferable that everything was parsed deterministically based only on the given pattern.